# Center buttons in columns with as little nesting as possible

Tags: android, android-layout

My goal to achieve the following:

[image]

center buttons, as if they are in two 50% width columns. I do this with this xml:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:gravity="center">
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="412-77"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:gravity="center">
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="22222"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

However I think it's too much nesting. My min sdk 2.2, so i can't use grid layout.
How to reduce nesting in xml?

Comment: You can use Relative Layout insted

Comment: try this :<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="412-77"/>

            <Button android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:text="22222"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot, i tried relative, but couldn't achive this result, can you show xml example

Comment: @krunalpatel, this is not that i want, gap between buttons always 20dp

Comment: Have you tried posted XML @orium

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code...

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:text="22222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
        android:text="412-77" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Another Way

This Might Be you Looking for

Comment: you just replace inner linearLayout with relative. I'm not see how this reduce view nesting

Comment: What do you need ?20dp Space between buttons ? I keep then center .

Comment: Just check this new XML file @orium

Comment: this is the same, as add margin. gap between buttons not depend on screen width. i want buttons position in like first button center in 33% width, second in 66% width position. And i think it's not possible to do with smaller nesting hierarchy.

Comment: Yes I think its near to impossible.

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this out:

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:alignparentLeft="true"
            android:text="412-77" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
             android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="22222" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```